# Laravel Nova 4 conditionally show field on preview

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-9

I am using Laravel 9 and Nova 4 and have a resource where a lot of the properties are nullable. I'd like the preview screen to only show a field if the value is not null. Looking at the nova docs methods like `showOnIndex()` and `showOnDetail()` etc accept a callback so that you can add a condition for whether to show them or not. Unfortunately the `showOnPreview()` doesn't accept a callback so is there another way that I can conditionally tell Nova to only show the field in the preview if the value isn't null?

Comment: I went through the Nova 4.2.1 source code but did not see any way of doing what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `showOnPreview` accepts callback and behaves like other `showOn*` actions.
I'm working with Nova v4.28.0 and the callback is available.

It seems the options have been added since @kobey checked version 4.2.1.